# Switching page numbering to roman format (and back) in classicthesis generates wrong hyperlinks

Tags: hyperref, page-numbering, classicthesis, roman-numerals

In this document hyperlinks in TOC to chapters 2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9 lead to starting pages of previous chapters (chaps. 1, 4 and 8 and all parts have proper hyperlinks):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrbook}

\usepackage{classicthesis}
%\usepackage{hyperref}

\title{Title}
\author{Author}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents%

\part{1}
\chapter{1}
\chapter{2}
\chapter{3}

\newcounter{savepage}
\setcounter{savepage}{\arabic{page}}
\cleardoublepage
\pagenumbering{Roman}

\part{2}
\chapter{4}
\chapter{5}
\chapter{6}

\cleardoublepage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{\thesavepage}

\part{3}
\chapter{7}
\chapter{8}
\chapter{9}

\end{document}
```

Switching the two lines:

```
\usepackage{classicthesis}
%\usepackage{hyperref}
```

to:

```
%\usepackage{classicthesis}
\usepackage{hyperref}
```

brings all chapter hyperlinks to work as intended.

**I know that using different page numbering schemes with `hyperref` labeling them in an unique manner tends to be tricky, but in this case `hyperref` by itself seems to proprely interpret page labels.** The problem starts only when `classicthesis` package is called instead (with indirect call to `hyperref`).

Is there any simple solution to this or a more proper way to achieving the desired result? I am not sure whether it is a bug or am I doing this not as it should be done.

Affected chapter hyperlinks are marked in the picture below.

[image]

---

EDIT: After esdd's solution almost everything works, apart from entries for LoT/LoF:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrbook}
\PreventPackageFromLoading[{\newcommand*\pdfstringdefDisableCommands[1]{}}]{hyperref}

\usepackage{classicthesis}

\ResetPreventPackageFromLoading
\let\pdfstringdefDisableCommands\relax
\usepackage{hyperref}
\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{\let\thepart=\relax}% I do not know if that is really needed

\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind} % adding list of figures and list of tables to table of contents

\cfoot*{Page \pagemark}% to show the page number

\newcounter{savepage}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\part{1}
\chapter{1}
\chapter{2}
\chapter{3}

\cleardoublepage
\setcounter{savepage}{\value{page}}
\pagenumbering{Roman}

\part{2}
\chapter{4}
\chapter{5}
\chapter{6}

\cleardoublepage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{\thesavepage}

\part{3}
\chapter{7}
\chapter{8}
\chapter{9}

\listoftables
\listoffigures
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @egreg commented (the comment was removed?) package `hyperref` is loaded to early.

Workaround: You can use `\PreventPackageFromLoading[...]{hyperref}` before package `classicthesis` and `\ResetPreventPackageFromLoading` when `classicthesis` is loaded. Both commands are provided by KOMA-Script package `scrlfile` that is loaded by the KOMA-Script classes automatically.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrbook}
\PreventPackageFromLoading[{\newcommand*\pdfstringdefDisableCommands[1]{}}]{hyperref}

\usepackage{classicthesis}

\ResetPreventPackageFromLoading
\let\pdfstringdefDisableCommands\relax
\usepackage{hyperref}
\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{\let\thepart=\relax}% I do not know if that is really needed

\cfoot*{Page \pagemark}% to show the page number

\newcounter{savepage}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\part{1}
\chapter{1}
\chapter{2}
\chapter{3}

\cleardoublepage
\setcounter{savepage}{\value{page}}
\pagenumbering{Roman}

\part{2}
\chapter{4}
\chapter{5}
\chapter{6}

\cleardoublepage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{\thesavepage}

\part{3}
\chapter{7}
\chapter{8}
\chapter{9}
\end{document}
```

---

**Update**

With a KOMA-Script class you can use option `listof=totoc` to get ToC entries for LoF and LoT. So you can remove package `tocbibind`from your updated MWE.

It seems that there is a second **workaround** needed to get the links for LoF and LoT right.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,
  listof=totoc% <- add a tocentry for LoF and LoT
]{scrbook}

\PreventPackageFromLoading[{\newcommand*\pdfstringdefDisableCommands[1]{}}]{hyperref}
\usepackage{classicthesis}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpretocmd\listoftoc{\cleardoublepage\phantomsection}{}{\PatchFailed}

\ResetPreventPackageFromLoading
\let\pdfstringdefDisableCommands\relax
\usepackage{hyperref}
\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{\let\thepart=\relax}% I do not know if that is really needed

\cfoot*{Page \pagemark}% to show the page number

\newcounter{savepage}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\part{1}
\chapter{1}
\chapter{2}
\chapter{3}

\cleardoublepage
\setcounter{savepage}{\value{page}}
\pagenumbering{Roman}

\part{2}
\chapter{4}
\chapter{5}
\chapter{6}

\cleardoublepage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{\thesavepage}

\part{3}
\chapter{7}
\chapter{8}
\chapter{9}

\listoftables
\listoffigures
\end{document}
```

Comment: This solution fixes problem for ordinary chapters, but not for lists of tables/figures (please refer to my edited quesiton).  Is it possible to extend it for these entries also?

Comment: See my updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

Set properly the page number: first ensure a page is ejected, then add 1 if the number is odd, because of the next `\cleardoublepage`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrbook}

\usepackage{classicthesis}

\newcounter{savepage}

\title{Title}
\author{Author}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\part{1}
\chapter{1}{\Huge\thepage}
\chapter{2}{\Huge\thepage}
\chapter{3}{\Huge\thepage}

\clearpage
\setcounter{savepage}{\value{page}}
\ifodd\value{savepage}\stepcounter{savepage}\fi
\cleardoublepage

\pagenumbering{Roman}

\part{2}
\chapter{4}{\Huge\thepage}
\chapter{5}{\Huge\thepage}
\chapter{6}{\Huge\thepage}

\cleardoublepage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{\value{savepage}}

\part{3}
\chapter{7}{\Huge\thepage}
\chapter{8}{\Huge\thepage}
\chapter{9}{\Huge\thepage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Still, those chapters link to previous ones and not to themselves, e.g. clicking on "5 5 V" in TOC leads to page III.

Comment: @Peter That's a bug in classicthesis, I believe. It happens also if I remove all the page number format changing business.